Trying to find a formula to sum searched data in LibreOffice calc without creating an intermediary table?
Let's say I have a table of requirements for items I can make and another table of prices for all needed ressource.

Is there a way to compute the sum of all the required products in the cells of the cost column without having to create another table with all the cost for every requirement for each item? And how?

OK, Got it : I need to use the matrix version of the function check the matrix checkbox in the functions assistant :
use vlookup to find not one, but all the ressources in the price table. Then us iferr to put 0 if the key not found (typically blank - I could also have put a blank record in the price table... And finally, take the sum of the resulting matrix.

